# Help to model time variant system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let's imagine we have a system comprised of nodes and links. We give each node an initial value. After simulation is started flow is present between nodes through connecting links. Relationship between flow magnitude and node values is represented with formulas given below for the simplest possible configuration comprised of two nodes A, B and one link connecting them.

[A]-------F------->[B]

$$F=f(A,B)$$
Flow magnitude between nodes is a function which depends on the value of the nodes A and B, which are connected by this link.
$$A = f(A_{t-\Delta t}, -F, \Delta t)$$
Value of the node A is a function of the previous value of A, flow magnitude and time which has passed since last computation
$$B = f(B_{t-\Delta t}, F, \Delta t)$$
Value of the node B is a function of the previous value of B, flow magnitude and time which has passed since last computation

Let's say that for the simplest model real functions look like below.

$$ F = (A-B)/100$$
$$A=A_{t-\Delta t} - F*\Delta t$$ 
$$B=B_{t-\Delta t} + F*\Delta t$$ and initial values 
$$A_{0}=10000$$ 
$$B_{0}=5000$$

How do I formally write this as a differential equation? This needs to be solved numerically by a software and results plotted against time at 0,1, N seconds. The number of nodes and links will grow so any guidance how to properly model this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can model it with difference equations:

$$A=A_{t-\Delta t} - F(A,B)\Delta t \tag{1}$$
$$B=B_{t-\Delta t} + F(A,B)\Delta t \tag{2}$$

$$A(t+\Delta t)=A(t-\Delta t) - 2F(A(t),B(t))\Delta t \tag{3}$$
$$B(t+\Delta t)=B(t-\Delta t) + 2F(A(t),B(t))\Delta t \tag{4}$$

Let $t=n\Delta t$ and write set $A(n)=A_n$, then we have:

$$A_{n+1}=A_{n-1} - 2F(A_n,B_n)\Delta t \tag{5}$$
$$B_{n+1}=B_{n-1} + 2F(A_n,B_n)\Delta t \tag{6}$$

We can also write (3),(4) as differential equations:

$$\lim_{\Delta t \to 0}\frac{A(t+\Delta t)-A(t-\Delta t)}{2\Delta t}=\frac{dA}{dt}(t) = - 2F(A(t),B(t)) \tag{7}$$
$$\lim_{\Delta t \to 0}\frac{B(t+\Delta t)-B(t-\Delta t)}{2\Delta t}=\frac{dA}{dt}(t) =2F(A(t),B(t))\tag{8}$$

Comment: Thanks mike! I think I will try to do this either in scilab or python.